# dataTables table no longer responds to click

Tags: php, datatables

I have http://communitychessclub.com/examine_T3.php, a dataTable list of chess games. I previously able to able to click a row and the game score would pop up, but I switched the data source to js and it doesn't work now. Can anyone tell me what to change?

```
game.js begins with: var dataSet = [
```

This is the html js code for the web page:

```
<script>

//<?php include('assets/games.js'); echo ";"; ?>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#cccr').DataTable( {
```

Is this next line the bad code?

```
"createdRow": function(row, data, index) {$(row).attr('game', data.game);},

"search": {"search": "<?php echo ($_GET['player']); ?>"},

  } );
```

Is this next line the erroneous code?

```
$("#cccr").on("click", "tbody tr", function() {
window.location.href = 'basic.php?game='+$(this).attr('game');
} );
} );

</script>
```

Comment: Check your browser console first for errors. Usually `CRTL` + `SHIFT` + `i`

Comment: This is javascript. No errors, just miscoding. But where?

Comment: If you know this is [tag:javascript] why are you tagging [tag:php]? Also, your code consists of syntax errors in your question so it should error in the console.

Comment: That's another thing I'd like to learn: how to specify an external js data file and lose the php include. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 1. You request a page. 2. The server processes the request and reply's with a response. 3. Your browser reads the response. 4. if the browser reads the response and it includes javascript it executes it. If you're not getting what I mean, PHP is not javascript aware, to PHP its just a string... So if you want to include a js file, echo it in such a way the browser understands what you mean.

Comment: I can specify the external javascript in dataTables in some way, presently unknown to me, I think. Maybe you're right! Not for nothing, but echoing an external file doesn't sound like 2017. Sounds like a work-around, Got an example?